# Is there a notion of basis for Banach spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Consider the Banach space $\ell^1(\mathbb N)$.

The sequence $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ feels like a kind of basis because every element $a\in\ell^1(\mathbb N)$ can be written as an absolutely convergent infinite linear combination $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}a(n)e_n$ in a unique way.

(Here $e_n$ denotes the vector whose $n$th entry is 1 and all of whose other entries vanish.)

The same is true for the Banach space $c_0(\mathbb N)$.

Is the above property of the sequence $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ appropriate in order to abstractly define a basis of a Banach space? Has this been considered?

Comment: See Schauder basis: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis

Comment: @KennyT, Soarer: Thank you for your help!

Comment: As pointed out by Soarer Schauder basis is what you want here, for completeness of the wiki question in the title I also would recommend the Hamel basis, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamel_basis,  which is sometimes very useful when constructing counter examples.

Comment: Two books you should look at: 1. The classic: [Lindenstrauss-Tzafriri](http://books.google.com/books?id=v9in9nUW5bsC), 2. A nice new one: [Albiac-Kalton](http://books.google.com/books?id=FkjCulO5xg0C). Two links you should follow: 3. [Per Enflo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Per_Enflo) 4. [Approximation property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_property)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Soarer points out: Yes, it is called a [Schauder basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis).